# How can I determine if there are any outstanding Yum transactions left to complete?

Tags: yum

When there are outstanding unfinished Yum transactions, Yum will output something like the following when running commands such as `yum update`:

```
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider
running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
```

**How can I determine if there are any unfinshed transactions without any side effects?** (E.g., parsing the output of `yum update` will cause plenty of side effects, such as updating repository metadata.)

---

`man 8 yum-complete-transaction` suggests that one can simply check for the existence of files matching `/var/lib/yum/{transaction-all,transaction-done}*` (emphasis mine):

> yum-complete-transaction  is  a  program  which  finds incomplete
>   or    aborted yum transactions on a system and attempts to complete 
>   them.    **It  looks  at the transaction-all* and transaction-done*
>   files which    can normally be found in /var/lib/yum if a yum 
>   transaction  aborted    in the middle of execution**.
>
> If  it finds more than one unfinished transaction it will attempt
>   to    complete the most recent one first. You can run it more than
>   once to    clean up all unfinished transactions.

However, this doesn't seem to be entirely accurate.  For instance,  I have a system where such files exist, but `yum-complete-transaction` reports that there are no transactions left to complete:

```
[myhost ~]% ls /var/lib/yum/{transaction-all,transaction-done}*
/var/lib/yum/transaction-all.2016-11-23.07:15.21.disabled
/var/lib/yum/transaction-done.2016-11-23.07:15.21.disabled
[myhost ~]% sudo yum-complete-transaction 
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
No unfinished transactions left.
```

And attempting to clean up the unfinished transaction files with `--cleanup-only` fails to remove those files:

```
[myhost ~]% sudo yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only                   
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
No unfinished transactions left.
[myhost ~]% ls /var/lib/yum/{transaction-all,transaction-done}*
/var/lib/yum/transaction-all.2016-11-23.07:15.21.disabled
/var/lib/yum/transaction-done.2016-11-23.07:15.21.disabled
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that outputs a count of the number of unfinshed transactions:

```
find /var/lib/yum -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'transaction-all*' -not -name '*disabled' -printf . | wc -c
```

---

According to the source code for `yum-complete-transactions` from `yum-utils`, all `/var/lib/yum/transaction-all*` files are counted as unfinshed transactions...

```
def find_unfinished_transactions(yumlibpath='/var/lib/yum'):
    """returns a list of the timestamps from the filenames of the unfinished
       transactions remaining in the yumlibpath specified.
    """
    timestamps = []
    tsallg = '%s/%s' % (yumlibpath, 'transaction-all*')
    #tsdoneg = '%s/%s' % (yumlibpath, 'transaction-done*') # not used remove ?
    tsalls = glob.glob(tsallg)
    #tsdones = glob.glob(tsdoneg) # not used remove ?

    for fn in tsalls:
        trans = os.path.basename(fn)
        timestamp = trans.replace('transaction-all.','')
        timestamps.append(timestamp)

    timestamps.sort()
    return timestamps
```

...except for those files ending with `disabled`:

```
    times = []
    for thistime in find_unfinished_transactions(self.conf.persistdir):
        if thistime.endswith('disabled'):
            continue
        # XXX maybe a check  here for transactions that are just too old to try and complete?
        times.append(thistime)

    if not times:
        print "No unfinished transactions left."
        sys.exit()
```

Unfortunately the latter code is inside the `main()` function of `yum-complete-transaction.py` and cannot be independently called.  If this code were more modularized, then it might be possible to write a Python script that more accurately checks for unfinished transactions than the shell pipeline given above.